# Startup Disk Creator "Checksums do not match"

Tags: boot, live-usb

So I tried to create a bootable USB dirve with Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 12.04 using an Ubuntu 14.04 iso.

The first USB drive I tried already had an old boot image on it and Startup Disk Creator gave me the "`Checksums do not match`" error. So I tried another USB drive that had never had a boot image installed and it worked!

Now when I tried to load a different version onto the second USB drive I get the "`Checksums do not match`" error again. So it seems that if a boot image is installed then Starup Disk Creator fails? How ca I get this to work?

Comment: format the drive?

Comment: Are you sure the iso is not corrupted? It can happen.

Answer (score 0):

when i had this kind of problem i usually format the usb drive, but if you do not want to format then there is a program, called `unetbootin`, which is available in software center.

Just install it and show it the iso file in your hard disk, and you have to specify your usb drive, unetbootin will replace previous data.

Comment: I tried unetbootin, but it would hang during boot. I ended up installing sudo apt-get install usb-creator-kde

Comment: sorry, i do understand what do you mean by it would hang during boot, and by the way if usb creator kde solve your problem then go with it